# datalist how to toggle on and off

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make it so that whenever the user click on the input box the options disappear and whenever they click on it again it reappears. My html code is above javascript below

```js
function test() {
  var data = document.getElementById("browsers")
  // data.toggle();
  var x = document.getElementById("a");
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```html
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
  <input id = "a" list="browsers" name="myBrowser" 
    style="width: 400px;" onclick="test()" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
```

Comment: try on input using an addeventListener

Comment: did not work same issue

Comment: If you try this without any javascript code, would that not meet your requirement?

Comment: function test() {
  const input = document.getElementById("a");
  const listProperty = input.getAttribute("list");
  const newListProperty = listProperty === "browsers" ? "" : "browsers";
  input.setAttribute("list", newListProperty);
}

Comment: thanks it works but it is a bit glitchy. the first thing you press the down error it automatically closes. the second time and everytime after you don't have this problem though